# Shared Maven Repository across developers

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Is there any way to avoid developers download all dependencies and have those dependencies located to shared locattion to all the developer and each developer working on project point to that location?

Can anyone explain with sample files and example?

Comment: You can specify local repository with `-Dmaven.repo.local` parameter or by adding `<localRepository>...</localRepository>` in your `settings.xml`. However as pointed by other comments this location is not concurrency-safe and *should be avoided*.

Answer (score 12):

Best is to go with one of the repository managers for maven. The main steps for the setup will be:

- Install a central repository on an internal machine
- Configure the central repository to proxy the repositories you need for your developers
- Modify the developers maven settings to use the internal maven repository as mirror for everything (see [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) for details)

There are 3 well-known repository managers available:

- JFrog Artifactory: https://jfrog.com/community/open-source/
- Apache archiva: https://archiva.apache.org/
- Sonatype Nexus: https://www.sonatype.com/products/sonatype-nexus-oss-download

I favorite Artifactory - the installation and configuration took less than an hour. Now if a developer adds a new dependency to a maven project, the artifact will be downloaded from the original remote repository to the internal repository and will be made available. When the next developer needs the archive it will be downloaded from the internal repository - the access will be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can change local repository like this:

```
The location of your local repository can be changed in your user configuration. The default value is ${user.home}/.m2/repository/.

<settings>
  ...
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo/</localRepository>
  ...
</settings>
```

[look this article](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html)

I think if you make shared folder and all other developers write path to this folder this can help.(but I didn't try this)

**UPDATE**

Using shared repo is bad idea. Sharing local repository between two or many users is not thread safe and may result in different errors.
So as many people mentioned here use [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview)

Comment: The local repository cache is not concurrent safe. If two developers are sharing the same one they will end up with corruption.

Comment: question was "is this any way" and my answer was some kind of way that he ca do this. but why you give me minus. I say that didn't do this.

Comment: You should point out *why* it is a bad idea. When you tell somebody how to holster a gun with the safety off and a bullet in the chamber, you should warn them about the risks to their foot!

Comment: if you edit the answer to include why sharing local repositories between users is a *bad plan* then I will happy change from a -1 to +1

Comment: I add some changes in answer but I can't give fully qualified answer because I didn't share local repo between two or more people

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for https://jfrog.com/community/open-source/

Artifactory has nice user-guide and easy to understand. I have not much experienced it but it is really powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want but i sure you that this is not a good idea. Because later conflit will happen as soon as 2 developer start working at once on same project

Answer (score 0):

Maven is resolving and updating dependencies. You´ll always have a local instance of your repo somewhere. You can configure the local repository and other profiles in the settings.xml in your .m2 folder.

For example the local repo looks like

`<localRepository>C:/dev/.m2/repository</localRepository>`

It probably also resolves shared filesystems.
You can also add an internal repository for your own maven artifacts on a fileshare as

```
<repository>
     <id>internal.releases.upload</id>
     <name>Internal repo</name>
      <url>file:////data/repo</url>
</repository>
```

for example. Read more about repositories here http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html