# Sharing Maven local repository

Tags: maven, maven-3

Maven stores all jars under local repository `~/.m2/repository/`. It occupies a lot of space when there are many users.

So, Is it possible to share this local repository by multiple users, perhaps under a different directory structure?

Comment: Can you define `a lot of space`? Furthermore what do you mean by `where there are many users`?

Comment: Don't do it: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623212/shared-maven-repository-across-developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can share the local repository. You just need a folder that all of you have write permission. e.g.: `/local/.m2/repository`. And to share this folder, you all can change the `settings.xml` with new local repository as below:

```
 <localRepository>/local/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

Also you all can use the `settings.xml` in `${MAVEN_HONE}/conf` and then you don't need to set private `settings.xml`.

Comment: That will lead to problems with your builds. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623212/shared-maven-repository-across-developers

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, it is. But always it's useful.

Comment: I don't think that this post should have been downvoted. @khmarbaise is right that it can lead to problems, but it *does* answer the asker's question. I think what the asker really wanted to know was simply how to change the location of the local repository so that it can be shared.

Comment: @Mike I disagree. Part of the question is "Is it possible to share this local repository by multiple users" and it seems the answer is "No, not in a safe manner". So any answer that suggests otherwise is not helpful to the community.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer No. The local reposiory is as the name implies for the user and not for multiple users. Apart from that Maven itself is not designed for that. It will usually come to problems.

Comment: Yes, there might be problems when shared, however, it is possible to share.

Comment: I would do it, cause it will lead to problems. Parallized access is not supported by Maven. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623212/shared-maven-repository-across-developers