# Share Maven repository ***only one user connected at a time***

Tags: maven

We have a bank of virtual machines used by developers to make changes and perform tests of a large suite of projects using Maven for dependency management. Each user has a unique login, so their local .m2/repository folders are separate from one another. I [have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006335/sharing-maven-local-repository) that sharing maven repositories is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623212/shared-maven-repository-across-developers) due to lack of thread-safety and general lack of concurrent access support.

My question is, is there a reason not to share local maven "repository" folders when only one user at a time will be using them? The limitation is a limitation of the host operating system - it is not possible for two users to log in to these machines simultaneously.

Comment: Use a maven repository manager to share dependencies and built artifacts. Examples are Nexus, Artifactory and Apache Archiva

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: In Maven the local repository is more akin to a cache. If you're using a CI system like Jenkins I would actually advise that you periodically purge the local repositories. This ensures your build can be performed "clean" from the source code and dependencies fetched from the upstream repositories. To "share" a repository you are best advised to do it the "Maven way" and setup a Maven repository manager, believe me it's not hard and worth the effort. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049948/when-is-it-safe-to-delete-the-local-maven-repository/10050239#10050239

Comment: Thanks. You still haven't answered my question, which is, "Is there a reason not to share these folders when only one user at a time will be using them?" The reasons given in prior answers to this question all relate to concurrent access. Is there a reason not to share these folders that does not relate to concurrent access?

Comment: The real problem is accessing the local repository simultaneously by two Maven runs (for example mvn install)...If this is not the case than there is no reason against it.

Comment: Thanks. I am likely to try this on at least one of the systems.