# Could not create local repository at .m2/repository

Tags: java, maven, repository

I have a problem with maven plugin execution. When I execute it as user TOM (owner) then everything is ok and works well. But when I execute as other user - from other group, then crash.

Owner of .m2/repository -> OK:

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /path/to/mvn/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /path/to/usrsettings/mvnsettings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/TOM/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /home/TOM/.m2/repository
```

Other user from other group -> NOT OK:

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /path/to/mvn/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /path/to/usrsettings/mvnsettings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/TOM/.m2/repository
[ERROR] Could not create local repository at /home/TOM/.m2/repository -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.repository.LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException: Could not create local repository at /home/TOM/.m2/repository
```

I have changed privileges for /home/TOM/.m2/repository and subdirectories and files, mvsettings.xml, but no changes. In mvnsettings.xml I have set:

```
<localRepository>/home/TOM/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

Any ideas? Can other user use not his .m2/repository?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Shared Maven Repository across developers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623212/shared-maven-repository-across-developers). Heed [the warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623212/shared-maven-repository-across-developers#comment20500090_14623289) lower down that page - it's not thread-safe to share a local repository between developers.

Comment: Thanks for answer Duncan. I understand this, but still i would like to share my local repo between two users, to not use central repo.

Comment: Why would you want to do that, knowing that it won't work correctly? Is it because deploying a central repo sounds like a lot of work? It's actually very easy to do.

Comment: Yes, it is really easy. But I don't want to deploy not finished jar. Access to .m2/repo is needed just for me, but from two other logins.

Comment: a few things to check : user tom and other user should belong to teh same group. And ownership of .m2 should be this specific group. Example: Typically in ubuntu, when a user is created a group with the same name is create. so tom would have a group "tom" and say harry would have a group harry. If you create a new group called devs on that machine and give tom and harry dev group. Now when .m2 is created the ownership will be with tom:tom. TO have user harry access to the .m2, you need to change it using chown tom:dev .m2 and then set appropriate permissions.

Comment: If you don't like to share it it's best to start using a repository manager (Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva). Furthermore sharing local repository does not work and might produce problems. Independent from your wish to do it this way. It is not intended to share a users Maven repository. Two other logins is not a reason to share a repository between. Just use it locally by user. That works.